# Flutter - How to show data from Model 1 and data from Model2 in one UI

Tags: flutter, dart

I successfully called http cho the ProductModel and now i dont know how to get the ProductDrugModel to show along with ProductModel
this is my Model1:

```
 class ProductModel {
  String productID;
  String drugbankID;
  String productName;
  String productLabeller;
  String productCode;
  String productRoute;
  String productStrength;
  String productdosage;
  String approved;
  String otc;
  String generic;
  String country;

  ProductModel(
      {this.productID,
      this.drugbankID,
      this.productName,
      this.productLabeller,
      this.productCode,
      this.productRoute,
      this.productStrength,
      this.productdosage,
      this.approved,
      this.otc,
      this.generic,
      this.country});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productID = json['productID'];
    drugbankID = json['drugbankID'];
    productName = json['productName'];
    productLabeller = json['productLabeller'];
    productCode = json['productCode'];
    productRoute = json['productRoute'];
    productStrength = json['productStrength'];
    productdosage = json['productdosage'];
    approved = json['approved'];
    otc = json['otc'];
    generic = json['generic'];
    country = json['country'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['productID'] = this.productID;
    data['drugbankID'] = this.drugbankID;
    data['productName'] = this.productName;
    data['productLabeller'] = this.productLabeller;
    data['productCode'] = this.productCode;
    data['productRoute'] = this.productRoute;
    data['productStrength'] = this.productStrength;
    data['productdosage'] = this.productdosage;
    data['approved'] = this.approved;
    data['otc'] = this.otc;
    data['generic'] = this.generic;
    data['country'] = this.country;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Model2:

```
  class ProductDrugModel {
  String drugbankID;
  String drugName;
  String drugDescription;
  String drugState;
  String drugIndication;
  String drugPharmaco;
  String drugMechan;
  String drugToxicity;
  String drugMetabolism;
  String drugHalflife;
  String drugElimination;
  String drugClearance;

  ProductDrugModel({
    this.drugbankID,
    this.drugName,
    this.drugDescription,
    this.drugState,
    this.drugIndication,
    this.drugPharmaco,
    this.drugMechan,
    this.drugToxicity,
    this.drugMetabolism,
    this.drugHalflife,
    this.drugElimination,
    this.drugClearance,
  });

  factory ProductDrugModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductDrugModel(
      drugbankID: json['drugbank_ID'],
      drugName: json['drugName'],
      drugDescription: json['drugDescription'],
      drugState: json['drugState'],
      drugIndication: json['drugIndication'],
      drugPharmaco: json['drugPharmaco'],
      drugMechan: json['drugMechan'],
      drugToxicity: json['drugToxicity'],
      drugMetabolism: json['drugMetabolism'],
      drugHalflife: json['drugHalflife'],
      drugElimination: json['drugElimination'],
      drugClearance: json['drugClearance'],
    );
  }
}
```

My api call

```
class RecommenedData {
  static Future<List<ProductModel>> getRecommened() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await 
     http.get(Uri.parse(Constants.PRODUCT_RECOMMENDED_TOP_10));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List listTrend = json.decode(response.body) as List;
        return listTrend.map((e) => 
         ProductModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to fetch data");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("No Internet Connection");
    }
  }
}
```

ProductDrugModel
This is how i get the ProductDrugModel object
THe input will be from ProductModel drugbankID

```
class ProductDrugInfoService {
  static Future<List<ProductDrugModel>> getProductDrugInfo(String input) async {
    try {
      var response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(Constants.PRODUCT_DRUG_INFOR + input));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List listTrend = json.decode(response.body) as List;
        return listTrend.map((e) => ProductDrugModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to fetch data");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("No Internet Connection");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get data from ProductDrugModel by pass the drugbankID to endponit url
then show that data to the UI along with ProductModel
Any suggestion ??
Please help ><

Comment: add productID in ProductDrugModel. it will be object inside object.

Comment: Can please share api and model parsing code?

Comment: I'm updated my post pls check again, hope to see any solution :<